# Rss feed shows 1970-01-01 pubDate?

Tags: php, rss

My rss feed show 1970-01-01 pubDate on my mobilesite and shows correct pubDate on the website. Is the feed corupt ? It was working 3 days ago thou.

Or maybe ive written the format in a non standard way ?

```
    function get_rss($url, $lang) {
    $rss = new rss_php;
    $rss->load($url);
    $items = $rss->getItems();

    // Sets the maximum items to be listed
    $max_items = 5;

    $count = 0;

    $html = '';
    foreach($items as $index => $item) {
    $pubdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(substr($item['pubDate'], 4)));
    $html .= '
    <ul class="rssList">
    <li class="itemDate"><span>' . $pubdate . '</span></li>
    <li class="itemTitle"><a href="'.$item['link'].'"                 title="'.$item['title'].'"                         rel="external">        
 <h2>'.$item['title'].'</h2></a></li>
    <li class="itemText"><span>'.$item['description'].'<span></li>
    </ul>';
    $count++; //Increase the value of the count by 1
    if($count==$max_items) break; //Break the loop is count is equal to the max_loop
    }    
     echo $html;
    }
```

Definition of rss_php

```
        class rss_php {

    public $document;
    public $channel;
    public $items;

    # load RSS by URL
        public function load($url=false, $unblock=true) {
            if($url) {
                if($unblock) {
                    $this->loadParser(file_get_contents($url, false, $this->randomContext()));
                } else {
                    $this->loadParser(file_get_contents($url));
                }
            }
        }
    # load raw RSS data
        public function loadRSS($rawxml=false) {
            if($rawxml) {
                $this->loadParser($rawxml);
            }
        }
```

Parser

```
   private function loadParser($rss=false) {
    if($rss) {
        $this->document = array();
        $this->channel = array();
        $this->items = array();
        $DOMDocument = new DOMDocument;
        $DOMDocument->strictErrorChecking = false;
        $DOMDocument->loadXML($rss);
        $this->document = $this->extractDOM($DOMDocument->childNodes);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of $item['pubDate'] ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with the locale settings. It's unable to translate the month "okt" (should be "oct" in English), but was working fine with "sep" (same in English). The `strtotime()` function only works in English but explains why it was working a few days ago, but not now.

You have three options:

1. You can fix the way dates are generated with strtotime using [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php). You need this in your RSS class, set the locale to English and output the dates.
2. Use [`CreateFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when reading the string, in conjunction with `SetLocale` when reading the date. You should be able to translate a foreign date.
3. Manually parse the date yourself. `Preg_match()` could be a good starter for that.

Option 1 is probably easiest, if you can.

---

Edit (based on comments and edited question)

As the item data is coming straight from the rss feed (and is not self-generated) then you're probably up for option 3 (manually parse the string yourself). As you're ignoring the days of the week, the only bit you need to convert is the month, so use str_replace:

```
foreach($items as $index => $item) {
    $pubdateForeignString = substr($item['pubDate'], 4);
    $pubdateEnglishString = str_replace(array('mai', 'okt', 'dez'), array('may', 'oct', 'dec'), $pubdateForeignString);
    $pubdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($pubdateEnglishString));
```

You only need to convert the months that are different - I've taken a stab at German, but if in doubt you could use date('M') in a loop with setlocale().

Comment: +1 I was about to write the same ... Good catch about the "working some days before"...

Comment: I think ill stick with the first one. Never used setlocale before thou. Is this right and where should i put it ? setlocale (LC_ALL, 'en_En');

Comment: I guess you've got it sussed, but there are different locales you can use. Usual format is en_EN and you'd set it before running the string date functions. You can revert back to normal with a blank locale.

Comment: Well not really , im working on it. Now we know what cause the issue now i need to fix.

Comment: It's probably needed in your parse class/function. If you add to the question (or post a new question) with the full parse function then we can probably help

Comment: I think i've added that? its not enough ? thx for the help btw

Comment: I'm guessing it's the "load parser" function er need to see. But can't be sure until we do see it...

Comment: Updated answer - hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks been struggling with this issue whole day, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason and for an item in your `for` loop the `$item['pubDate']` is not defined (or it contains garbage) and `date` defaults to 1970-01-01. Make sure that your variable is always set and contains a date in a valid [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

Debug your loop and for each `item` print its contents: `var_dump($item['pubDate'])` to investigate further

Comment: string(28) "ti, 09 okt 2012 06:45:00 GMT" string(28) "to, 04 okt 2012 13:10:00 GMT" string(28) "ti, 02 okt 2012 13:40:00 GMT" string(29) "må, 01 okt 2012 10:40:00 GMT" string(28) "ti, 25 sep 2012 09:35:00 GMT"